# trying to erase the input after clicked the button and understand why in the console the array isn´t updated

Tags: javascript, events

I made a form and when submitted with valid data it goes to an empty array that I created to save userData.
First problem - When submitted the valid data I want to erase again the inputs to add new data.

Second problem - when I go to the console to see if it works the array stops putting new data if I check what is inside.that is normal? I wanted to always upgrade the array with more objects.

Thank you in advanced

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="add-form">
  <label for="txtUser">User Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtUser" name="firstName" placeholder="name">
  <label for="txtPass">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="txtPass" name="yourPassword" placeholder="password">
  <button id="submit">Enter</button>
</form>



 <script>

   (function(){
      'use strict'

       const form =document.querySelector('#add-form')
       const user = document.querySelector('#txtUser')
       const pass = document.querySelector('#txtPass')
       const submit = document.querySelector('#submit')

       const saveData = []


       form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
           e.preventDefault()

           if(e.target.elements.firstName.value === '' || 
              e.target.elements.yourPassword.value === ''){

              alert('enter some valid text')

           }else{

              let nameData = e.target.elements.firstName.value
              let passData = e.target.elements.yourPassword.value
              saveData.push({
                  userName: nameData,
                  userPass: passData
              })

         //problem: doesn't erase the input after entering the button 
              nameData = ''
              passData = ''
         }

      })

      console.log(saveData)

    })()


</script>
```

I expect to erase the input after submit the correct valid data and  actualize the array of objects with new information submitted on the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the value of the control into a variable, and then blanking the variable - you are not blanking the value of the control.

Instead of blanking the variable...

```
nameData = ''
passData = ''
```

Blank the control...

```
e.target.elements.firstName.value = '';
e.target.elements.yourPassword.value = '';
```

---

Another way of doing it would be to store the control and use that directly...

```
let nameCtrl = e.target.elements.firstName;
let passCtrl = e.target.elements.yourPassword;
saveData.push({
    userName: nameCtrl.value,
    userPass: passCtrl.value
})
nameCtrl.value = ''
passCtrl.value = ''
```

Comment: You're welcome @Raquel - good luck with the rest of your project. (Oh, and the 2nd part of question, which I forgot to answer, is that you need to put your `console.log` within the event handler function... at the moment it's outside of the function and will only run once)

Comment: Right twice in one month... it's a new record ;-)  You're welcome Raquel :-)